# Software to make product video demos?

Tags: video, demo

What kind of software do you think is used to make demos,like the once seen in PDC etc by Microsoft or seen on Channel 9.

Example:
http://download.microsoft.com/download/c/e/2/ce28874c-4f44-4dbd-babb-727685e2be96/WinFS_IWish_720x486_2mbs.wmv

Basically you have text and sound.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I bet they use [Camtasia Studio](http://www.techsmith.com/camtasia.asp)

Comment: @abmv actually they do quite often, you can always tell by the green orb in the systray on the machine they are recording. They do use Camtasia Studio quite often

Answer (score 0):

[SnagIt](http://www.techsmith.com/screen-capture.asp) is totally rad

Answer (score 0):

Also check out

- [Debugmode Wink](http://www.debugmode.com/wink/)
- [Camstudio](http://camstudio.org/)

Both are fully featured and free

Answer (score 0):

[xvidcap](http://xvidcap.sourceforge.net/)(GPL) for any X session, for example GUIs on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

ShowBiz is open to make all kinds of videos. find the tutorial on [how to make videos](http://www.arcsoft.com/topics/video-editor/how-to-make-a-video.html) here